# How to filter query in Laravel Factories

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I've got a foreign key of a user_id in my Listing table.
In my ListingFactory I can put the user_id of a random user in that spot, but my user also has a is_seller bool. How can I make it so the query in my ListingFactory only gives me an array of users with is_seller=true?
This is my code so far:

```
$factory->define(Listing::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $randomSellerId = \App\User::where('is_seller', true)->pluck('id')->toArray();
    return [
        'seller_id' => $faker->randomElement($randomSellerId),
    ];
});
```

This code still puts all the users, including the ones with is_seller=false, into the `$randomSellerId` array

Answer (score 0):

You Dont Need to Convert the Collection to array

Laravel Collection has out of the box method `random`

```
$factory->define(Listing::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $allSellerId= \App\User::where('is_seller', true)->pluck('id');
    return [
        'seller_id' => $allSellerId->random(),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, but it's still putting seller_ids of users with is_seller=false in the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random id using the following.

```
$randomId = \App\User::where('is_seller', true)->inRandomOrder()->value('id')
```